# Rails 3 named routes - no route matches

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm pretty new to Rails and I'm stuck getting a named route working properly.  There are a lot of similar questions but I think I've got a different problem.  It's the first time I've used a named route with a parameter.

Firstly, this is Rails 3.0.9.  I've got an entry in routes.rb:

```
get '/tasklist/:id' => 'projects#task_list'
```

Running rake routes shows the line:

```
 GET   /tasklist/:id(.:format)    {:controller=>"projects", :action=>"task_list"}
```

My view has the following code:

```
<%= link_to image_tag("icons/add.png"), tasklist_path, :id => project.id %>
```

But when displaying the view it shows an error:

```
No route matches {:controller=>"projects", :action=>"task_list"}
...
Extracted source (around line #39): 
39:   <td><%= link_to image_tag("icons/add.png"), tasklist_path, :id => project.id %></td>
```

I just can't see where the problem is here.  Note that visiting the URL http://localhost:3000/tasklist/2 does appear to work just fine.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding `:as => "tasklist"` to your route.

Comment: Oh, and it should be `tasklist_path(project.id)`. You defined your route as requiring an :id and aren't passing it to the path helper

Comment: OK - just had a go at this: <%= link_to image_tag("icons/add.png"), tasklist_path, :id => project.id, :as => "tasklist" %> - but unfortunately I still get just the same error

Comment: I tried putting the id into the tasklist_path, but that gives me a different error - format=>1 ??: No route matches {:controller=>"projects", :action=>"task_list", :format=>1}

Comment: In your routes file, you'd write: get '/tasklist/:id', :to => 'projects#task_list', :as => 'tasklist'. That'll get you the named route, tasklist_path(:id). Then in your view you'd write: <%= link_to image_tag("icons/add.png"), tasklist_path(project.id) %>